# What are the benefits of using pseudo-residuals in Gradient Boosting?

Tags: boosting, loss-functions, gradient

At each iteration $t$ of the Gradient Boosting algorithm, we're basically trying to add the weak learner $f_t$ that minimizes:

$$
\mathcal{L}_t = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} l(y_i, \hat{y}_i^{(t-1)} + f_t(\mathbf{x}_i))
$$

where $l$ is arbitrary differentiable loss function and $\hat{y}_i^{(t-1)}$ prediction from the previous iteration.

However, **instead of trying to learn optimal $f_t(\mathbf{x}_i)$ so as to minimize $\mathcal{L}_t$ directly**, we compute **pseudo-residuals** by differentiating the loss function $l$ and fit weak learners with those.

What are the benefits of learning pseudo-residuals instead of optimizing $\mathcal{L}_t$ directly?

Comment: Some of the answers [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/31609/why-do-we-use-gradients-instead-of-residuals-in-gradient-boosting) may be helpful.

Comment: Agree, I've found various questions similar to this one, but none of them actually asks about benefits of fitting pseudo-residuals vs $\mathcal{L}_t$ directly. In the XGBoost paper, they mention that "*Second-order approximation
can be used to quickly optimize the objective in the general
setting*" but they do not elaborate why's that the case. However, some of the points (such as optimizing unified loss for the speedup) are mentioned in this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/204377/210606) though.